# a localhost https java application with servlets

Tags: java, servlets, https

i have to design a localhost application that one code at other project returns one url that follows like this..

http://localhost:8080/MyProject?id="somevalue"

now my task to implements the https( the url that is generated by the other project is hard coded.So we can have the https url also....as the other project is also one of my projects but after the task is over it will return url with id as parameter)

So let us have the url of the type

https://localhost:8443/MyProject?id="somevalue"

my design things are as follows.

```
1. i have to use https 
2.i have to use RSA bit length of 512 bits
3.i have to be able to read the value id with request.getParameter()
4.How https coding will be different from http in servlets..
can we use the same coding of http in https..
```

i do not need the complex implementation. what i need is just it has to appear https and In the servlet implementation i want to use http coding...

Is it possible..

Thank you..

Comment: This should be just a matter of changing the configuration of the servlet container / web server. No code changes necessary.

Comment: Thank you..i have some doubts on myself taking a step...you cleared my doubt..i will go through the steps...i have searched the same in internet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code shouldn't be affected if you are moving from Non SSL to SSL, assuming you are using tomcat, please read documentation to configure [SSL](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

Comment: what do you mean by shouldn't be affected....are you saying that there  is no worry to change the code if we are moving from non ssl to ssl..

Comment: yeah correct no change in code, in real world applications dont even have the knowledge about ssl or non ssl, your secure your server on a general note.